# Not able to access div value

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have div, and the div record gets added dynamically using jquery
Now i want the div record should be used in code behind C# so i can insert the value in Database.
when i specify runat="server" in my div,my recorded not gets bind in div.

```
//Jquery Code
var NewData = '<div class="col-sm-12">' + x + '   ' + y + '  ' + txtName.value + ' &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF" data-marker="m_' + x + '_' + y + '">Remove</a> </div>';
$("#divdynamicData").append(NewData);

//HTML code
<div id="divdynamicData"></div>
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveTODB" runat="server" Text="SaveToDB" OnClick="btnSaveTODB_Click" />
```

what i want is when use click on SaveTODB button, if my div contain 50 record it should be added in DB but before that i want access of this div in code behind

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty well sir i am fresher and new to StackOverflow...my question is i want to access my div data which is added dynamically inside the code behind using C#

Comment: When you add the div, also add the attributes of ````runat='server'```` and a ````ID````.   That way you can access it via code-behind.

Comment: @JohnPete22 thank sir for your reply. i have try this and it is working `$("#<%= divdynamicData.ClientID %>").append(NewData); <div id="divdynamicData" runat="server"></div>`  but when i click on the button my div value gone

Comment: Are you re-building the 'div' on PostBacks? When you click on a button, it's going to reload the page before it handles the Click_Event.

Comment: @JohnPete22 sir i am trying to insert the DIV data into DATABASE but dont know how to loop through this div and once i click on the button all the record gone...

Comment: Whether you're inserting into a DB or wherever, you are trying to access the 'div' and it's controls from CODE-BEHIND right? If so, ASP.NET button click is going to cause a PostBack and the dynamically created 'div' needs to be re-created before you can access it.

Comment: @JohnPete22 i working on it. give you the update. thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery to call c# method from your front end.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Jquery to get data on button click.

```
<script>
  Jquery.('#btnSaveTODB').click(function(){
     $.post('Home/GetSaveData?NewData=' +NewData,function(res){
           alert('Data Sent');
     });
   });
</script>
```

In your C# class

```
[Web Method]
public void GetSaveData(string NewData)
{
     ///Your c# code here
}
```